# Websocket server not getting a handshake when ws:// changed to wss://

Tags: websocket

We are completely stuck and would love help from someone who has worked on WSS and knows some cloud infrastructure.

We built a custom websocket server in a style similar to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server). The server is run on a VM in Azure on port 45001. The client is our website (HTML/Javascript). The websocket uri is 'ws://endpointname:45001' The server would get a handshake request and send the appropriate response and a connection was established. The client and server communicated happily every after!

The moment we installed an SSL certificate where our website is hosted on Azure, the browser asked us to convert ws calls wss://. By doing this, the first message that was hitting the server port that was an HTTP upgrade request is now some encrypted message that server can’t make sense of!!!

```
//Used to convert the first messages to string. The string used to be the handshake request
//But when connected via wss, this string is meaningless gibberish.

String data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Any ideas why the server VM is not getting an HTTP upgrade request?

Things we tried:

1. Installed the certificate on port 45001 of the VM. No luck. Not sure how the VM would even know to use this cert to decrypt.
2. Ran the server locally and let the browser connect via wss. The server still got weird encrypted messages. In the local environnment, on what basis does

Would really appreciate if someone can help.!!!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP and HTTPS are typically used on different ports (80 and 443 by default, respectively).  A Secure WebSocket client has to connect to the server and establish an HTTPS session before it can then send a normal WS upgrade request.

If you try to run HTTP and HTTPS on the same port, most servers will not handle that correctly, unless they are specifically designed to peek the first few bytes of a new connection to determine if HTTPS is being used or not.  It is usually easier to just use separate ports instead, one dedicated to HTTP and one dedicated to HTTPS.

In your case, it sounds like your WSS client is still connecting to the unsecure WS port, and so the server would see an HTTPS encryption handshake instead of an unencrypted HTTP request.  The HTTPS handshake is a binary protocol, not textual, so it would appear like gibberish if you try to view it as text.

Port 45001 is not a standard HTTP/S port, so you must be specifying it explicitly in your `ws://` and `wss://` urls.  You need to update the `wss://` urls to use a port that the server has been configured to support HTTPS on.

Comment: Thanks!!! I edited my post to clarify that we are specifying the port number in url. Can you please answer 1) In ws:// model we were simply responding back to client on receiving the 1st message on the port, which was an upgrade request, agreeing to the upgrade and supplying other necessary stuff. Now that we are receiving messages via wss, does that mean we need send messages back and do the handshake programmatically? 2) the cert is installed on the VM port. Is that enough for server to do the handshake itself and we then get the upgrade request?

Comment: Please read Azure's documentation on how to enable HTTPS ([Configuring SSL for an application in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/) and [Enable HTTPS for an app in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/)), and also see [How to setup a Web Server in an Azure Virtual Machine](https://www.nimbo.com/blog/how-to-setup-an-azure-virtual-machine-as-a-web-server/).

Comment: Your second link for adding certificates to app services (our front end app - HTML), we have implemented it. 
Your first link is for classic cloud services which dont have a VM behind. Since we have a VM behind it, its not applicable to us. See http://serverfault.com/questions/722796/install-ssl-certificate-on-azure-cloud-service-vm We added cert to VM as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791(v=vs.110).aspx). Your third link regarding configuring VM for HTTPS is also [implemented](http://take.ms/ohCft). Any ideas on what to do ?